# Ubuntu - Notifications/alarm after end of job execution in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I work with a lot of simulations which often take sometime. In the meantime, I would prefer spending time writing article or other jobs. I have to check periodically when the simulation is going to end. Since there are lots of experts here, I wanted to ask which is the best way to notify when the job execution is done from terminal. Preferably a visual notification (like popup)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Superuser](https://superuser.com) might be more relevant for this question. For example this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/345455).

The simplest way would be to use `notify-send`:

```
sleep 5 && notify-send 'done'
```